# Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

so i'm using a docker compose to start kafka and zookeeper ,

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.6
#      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.3.54
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "configs:1:1,domainEvents:1:1,derivedEvents:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    depends_on:
      - "zookeeper"
```

but when i see the kafka logs i keep getting this error

```
[2020-06-11 12:37:00,737] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2020-06-11 12:37:00,749] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2020-06-11 12:37:00,753] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 1001]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2020-06-11 12:37:01,011] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
[2020-06-11 12:37:01,133] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Started data-plane processors for 1 acceptors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2020-06-11 12:37:01,141] INFO Kafka version: 2.3.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2020-06-11 12:37:01,141] INFO Kafka commitId: fc1aaa116b661c8a (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2020-06-11 12:37:01,142] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1591879021134 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2020-06-11 12:37:01,144] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
creating topics: configs:1:1
creating topics: domainEvents:1:1
creating topics: derivedEvents:1:1
[2020-06-11 12:37:35,825] ERROR [KafkaApi-1001] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
[2020-06-11 12:37:35,825] ERROR [KafkaApi-1001] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
[2020-06-11 12:37:43,568] ERROR [KafkaApi-1001] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

this used to work before , but i'm running this code after few weeks and i keep getting this error. what could have gone wrong??

Comment: `This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet` Did you try after the brokers are up?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the `ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME`?

Comment: @JavaTechnical yes there is a broker running

Comment: @RobinMoffatt it was a solution another issue i had faced before

Comment: It's probably the wrong solution :-P Remove it, and see if this problem here remains. If it doesn't, then we can address your other issue afterwards.

Comment: (listeners reference: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-11&utm_term=rmoff-devx )

Comment: @RobinMoffatt the ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME seems to be a requisite for the docker image used: https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/README.md#pre-requisites